# ngIf not working for Span Container in Angular 8

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

I am using the following code to show and hide a span container. This seems not working.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="completed==false">
    <span>Working.......</span><br />
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="completed==true">
    <span>Working Complete</span><br />
</ng-container>
```

I have tried putting `*ngIf` within the span tag, this is also not working. The variable `completed` is working on subsequent usages like

```
<div *ngIf="completed==false" class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
```

Comment: post your ts file for the `completed` definition and usage

Comment: Maybe your valuable is never false. You can do it via a of-else syntax. Or leave the true/false of the equation.